# Getting Assembly Description from assembly file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework

How do i get assembly description that i have added in assemblyinfo.cs file in my compact framework windows mobile 6 .

I get my build version from

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.Revision.ToString()
```

Now how do i get assembly description ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
     var descriptionAttribute = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyDescriptionAttribute), false).OfType<AssemblyDescriptionAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
var description = descriptionAttribute .Description;
```